# Magento Sagepay iFrame is empty

Tags: magento, opayo

I have a site based on magento. I updated magento to 1.7.0.2 and the Sagepay extension stopped working. The form(where you can put your card details) should be displayed in an iframe but now it's empty. I updated the sagepay to the latest version, I chekcedall configuration on the admin page. Does somebody have any idea what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: itz cuz sagepay is just compatible with 1.6 and before. So you have wait until they owner of sagepay update it.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-sage-pay-suite-ce-sage-pay-approved.html
If you check the releases it should support magento 1.7.
And I'm also able to configure it on the admin page.

Comment: It is compatible with 1.7.0.2, I just finished one yesterday using the Sagepay Suite. I will bet its a JavaScript conflict. If you have any jQuery on your checkout page the result is what you are seeing.

Comment: I checked it but it doesn't use jquery at all.